# SQL syntax with MAX

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

I am wanting to find the MAX value after subtracting a column from one another column. What I have currently does not seem to work syntactically.

```
SELECT
    [EmpName] as 'Employee Name',
    MAX([EndYear]-[BeginYear]) as 'Total Years'
FROM
    [dbo].[EMPLOYEE];
```

Comment: Are you looking for the employee name with the greatest number of total years?  Or are you looking for the total number of years for each employee?

Comment: The employee name with the greatest number of total years, and if there is more than one, I want all of them.

Comment: MAX() is an aggregate function, so you need a GROUP BY if you have more than one employee.  However, I am not certain why you are using MAX() in your query above...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use something along these lines...

```
;WITH emps AS (
    SELECT 
        [EmpName] AS 'EmployeeName',
        [EndYear] - [Begin Year] AS 'TotalYears'
    FROM    
        [dbo].[Employee]
)

SELECT * FROM emps WHERE TotalYears = (SELECT MAX(TotalYears) FROM emps)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the [RANK](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176102.aspx) statement.

```
SELECT *, 
    RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY [Employee Name] ORDER BY [Total Years] DESC) AS Ranking
FROM
(
    SELECT EmpName AS 'Employee Name', EndYear - BeginYear AS 'Total Years'
    FROM Employee
) TotalYears
WHERE Ranking = 1
```

Keep in mind, I haven't actually tested the above SQL yet, I just wrote it from memory. I'll go spin up a database now to check syntax.

Answer (score 1):

Max statements have to work on aggregate data so add a group by.

```
SELECT
    [EmpName] as 'Employee Name',
    MAX([EndYear]-[BeginYear]) as 'Total Years'
FROM
    [dbo].[EMPLOYEE]
group by EmpName;
```